# I am unable to install truflle

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, truffle

This is the output when I run `sudo npm install -g truffle` and a complete log file.

> 40 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/truffle failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1123:443

This is the output shown on the terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some requirements problem.
You can try this(https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/installation) one.